# Adding custom "from" email in Amazon SES similar to sendgrid

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, sendgrid, amazon-ses

I have been using Sendgrid for sometime, and I like the service but after 100,000 emails quota the pricing jumps. I was looking at AWS SES service, but was unclear if "from" email address can be custom set without verification similar to sendgrid. My app users send emails to their personal contact list from my app so I want their contacts to see my users personal email in the "from" email when their contact reads the mail.

Or Does all my users have to verify their email address through Amazon even though My app has already verified their email address at App account Signup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app users cannot use their personal email as a MAIL FROM unless it's verified in SES (either the specific email address or its domain).

> The MAIL FROM domain must be a subdomain of the verified identity
>   (email address or domain) from which you will send your emails.

See [Using a Custom MAIL FROM Domain with Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html) for more details.